# Subtracting Two Columns In SQL After Join

Tags: sql

I have one table called Orders

```
PurchaseID VARCHAR
purchaseDate DATETIME
purchasePrice FLOAT
```

I want to find the difference between the purchase price on one day versus another day - The puyrchaseID will be the same.(This is just an example table of course)

```
SELECT a.purchasePrice AS purchasePriceDay1 ,  b.purchasePrice AS  purchasePriceDay1
from Orders a , Orders b
where a.PurchaseID = b.PurchaseID
```

Would that actually work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.PurchaseID, 
    ABS(a.PurchaseID - b.PurchaseID) AS diff
FROM 
    PurchaseID a INNER JOIN PurchaseID b ON a.PurchaseID=b.PurchaseID
WHERE a.PurchaseID=? 
    AND a.purchaseDate=? 
    AND b.purchaseDate=?
```

Fill in the placeholders with the ID and dates to compare.

Consult your DBMS documentation to see if you have the math [absolute function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

Comment: @Benoit how can we modify this query to include only rows "ABS(a.PurchaseID - b.PurchaseID) > 10"

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably also want to add `AND a.purchaseDate <> b.purchaseDate`

Comment: Why? What if I want to know that the price didn't change on the same day :P

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like

```
SELECT a.purchasePrice AS p1,  b.purchasePrice AS  p2, a.purchasePrice - b.purchasePrice as difference
from Orders a inner join Orders b on a.PurchaseID = b.PurchaseID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ((SELECT purchasePrice FROM Orders WHERE PurchaseID = 1 AND purchaseDate = '2010-06-21') - (SELECT purchasePrice FROM Orders WHERE PurchaseID = 1 AND purchaseDate = '2010-06-20')) AS diff;
```

Comment: It's the same as your solution, only with subselects instead of a join. Either way, if you use an index to search on, it's not gross at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the subtracting right in the query as well if you want to. You probably also want to make sure you don't get two purchases from the same day:

```
SELECT a.purchasePrice AS purchasePriceDay1 ,  b.purchasePrice AS  purchasePriceDay2, (purchasePriceDay2-purchasePriceDay1) AS purchasePriceDelta
from Orders a , Orders b
where a.PurchaseID = b.PurchaseID
and a.PurchaseDate < b.PurchaseDate
```