# Subtract two numeric columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to find the subtraction of two columns where each column might be a positive or negative values.

eg.

```
+------+------+------+
| colA | colB | colC |
+------+------+------+
| -100 |  100 |    0 |
|  200 | -200 |    0 |
| -300 | -400 | -100 |
|  200 |  300 |  100 |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: `select colB - colA` would give you the result in colC

Comment: der is there / the in german @Sami i just missed it in the original edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting Two Columns In SQL After Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087941/subtracting-two-columns-in-sql-after-join)

Comment: @Sami is there a point you are trying to make?

Comment: @gopu Your example shows addition, not subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

If [colC] is what you're trying to get, you're just doing simple addition, not really subtraction:

- [-100] + [100] = [0]
- [-300] + [-400] = [-700]

  SELECT colA
      , colB
      , TotalValue = colA + colB
  FROM yourTable;

Comment: yeah may be when the column is both negative/one is negative but when

Comment: both are positive like colA is 100,colB is 100

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

- If both columns are position, then we take the answer to be an absolute value, because it would be a positive integer like this:

  - `abs(colA - colB)`
- If both columns are negative, we can make ONE of the columns an absolute value and then add them like this:

  - `abs(colA) + colB`
- If either logic is false, then it is likely one column is negative and the other is positive, so we can use RussellFox's logic:

  - `colA + colB`

So put it all together:

```
select colA
       ,colB
       ,colC = case when colA > 0 and colB > 0 then abs(colA - colB)
                    when colA < 0 and colB < 0 then abs(colA) + colB
                    else colA + colB
               end
from mytable
```

Here's a [rextester sample](http://rextester.com/XQY17526) for you to play with

Answer (score -1):

It really comes down to the precise requirement you have in mind for building the logic.

```
select
, colA
, colB
, abs(abs(colA) - abs(colB)) as Abs_Value
, abs(colA) - abs(colB) as Abs_Value_Diff
, colB - abs(colA) as Abs_Value_Diff2

, case when colA >= 0 and colB >= 0 then colB - colA
    when colA < 0 and colB < 0 then colB - colA
    when colA < 0 and colB >= 0 then colB - abs(colA)
    when colA >= 0 and colB < 0 then abs(colB) - colA
    else colB - colA 
    end as Abs_Value_Diff3
from 
test_table
order by TestField1;
```